# How To Make The Object Creation Dynamic, Means According To User Choice

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

```
public class SaveDataDTO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Film Objects
        FilmDTO fdto1 = SpringGetBean.getFilmDTOBean();
        fdto1.setfName("Avengers");

        FilmDTO fdto2 = SpringGetBean.getFilmDTOBean();
        fdto2.setfName("Exodus Gods And Kings");

        FilmDTO fdto3 = SpringGetBean.getFilmDTOBean();
        fdto3.setfName("Fast And The Furious 7");

        // Genre Objects
        GenreDTO gdto1 = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
        gdto1.setgName("Action");

        GenreDTO gdto2 = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
        gdto2.setgName("Science Fiction");

        GenreDTO gdto3 = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
        gdto3.setgName("Fiction");

        // Adding The Films To List
        List<FilmDTO> flaef = new ArrayList<FilmDTO>();
        flaef.add(fdto2);

        List<FilmDTO> flae = new ArrayList<FilmDTO>();
        flae.add(fdto1);

        List<FilmDTO> flf = new ArrayList<FilmDTO>();
        flf.add(fdto3);

        // Adding The Genre To List
        List<GenreDTO> glasf = new ArrayList<GenreDTO>();
        glasf.add(gdto1);
        glasf.add(gdto2);
        glasf.add(gdto3);

        List<GenreDTO> glas = new ArrayList<GenreDTO>();
        glas.add(gdto1);
        glas.add(gdto2);

        List<GenreDTO> glf = new ArrayList<GenreDTO>();
        glf.add(gdto3);

        // Association Of Objects In Both Directions
        fdto1.setGenres(glas);
        fdto2.setGenres(glasf);
        fdto3.setGenres(glf);

        gdto1.setFilms(flae);
        gdto2.setFilms(flae);
        gdto3.setFilms(flf);

        // Hibernate Methods
        Session session = MyHibernateSession.getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        try {
            session.save(fdto1);
            session.save(fdto2);
            session.save(fdto3);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

}
```

This Is Working Fine, But How To Make Things Here Dynamically, Actually Every Thing is Hard Coded Here, Also I Want To Map Things According To User Choice. So If Anyone Can Help Me In This Code

Comment: What you want to make dynamic here?

Comment: What do you want to make dynamic in this. Please explain more.

Comment: Creation Of All The Object, Adding To List And Which Object Should Be Associated With Which Object, All These Things Should Be Done According To User Choice. Right Now All The Things Are Static, There Are only 3 Object of "FilmDTO" and 3 Object Of "GenreDTO", I want them to create according to user input.

Answer (score 0):

i have refactored code for you :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FilmDTO fdto1 = SpringGetBean.getFilmDTOBean();
    fdto1 .setGenres(addGenre("Action", "Science Fiction"));

    FilmDTO fdto2 = SpringGetBean.getFilmDTOBean();
    fdto2.setGenres(addGenre("Action", "Science Fiction", "Fiction"));

    FilmDTO fdto3 = SpringGetBean.getFilmDTOBean();
    fdto3.setGenres(addGenre("Fiction"));

    GenreDTO gdto1 = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
    gdto1.setFilms(addFilm("Avengers"));

    GenreDTO gdto2 = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
    gdto2.setFilms(addFilm("Exodus Gods And Kings"));

    GenreDTO gdto3 = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
    gdto3.setFilms(addFilm("Fast And The Furious 7"));

    // Hibernate Methods
    Session session = MyHibernateSession.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
        session.save(fdto1);
        session.save(fdto2);
        session.save(fdto3);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

private static List<GenreDTO> addGenre(String... genre) {
    List<GenreDTO> list = new ArrayList<GenreDTO>();
    for (String gn : genre) {
        GenreDTO g = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
        g.setgName(gn);
        list.add(g);
    }
    return list;
}

private static List<FilmDTO> addFilm(String film) {
    List<FilmDTO> filmList = new ArrayList<FilmDTO>();
    FilmDTO f = SpringGetBean.getFilmDTOBean();
    f.setfName(film);
    return filmList;

}
```

and of course we can further refactor this but this much look more close to you logic. now user only have to specify film name or its genre you can pass those into your code to make it dynamic

**Update:**

You can further make dynamic films objects  like this, Here you only need to pass list of film names

```
 List<String> films = Arrays.asList("Avengers", "Exodus Gods And Kings", "Fast And The Furious 7");

    // Hibernate Methods
    Session session = MyHibernateSession.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
        for (String film : films) {
              GenreDTO g = SpringGetBean.getGenreDTOBan();
              g.setFilms(addFilm(film));
              session.save(g);
        }
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: But still only six object will get created three of FilmDTO and three of GenreDTO, I want them create according to user choice, how many movies user want to insert and also how many genres user want to insert for a particular movie.

Comment: that also possible. from this point achieving your target is very easy. i would highly encourage you to try doing that. if you will still unable to do that then i will help you out :) .. also try to read CODE REFACTORING techniques, that will help you in doing this

Comment: i have updated my answer in regard of your scenario.